# geoxml3 marker from Google Places Library response

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3

Someone knows how to translate a response from the Google Places Library into something geoxml3 can understand and render?

Work so far:

This works well for me

```
var a = {
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(12, 13),
    radius: 1000
};
var places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
places.search(a,searchCallback);
...
(in searchCallback function)    
var m = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: place.LatLng});
```

but I also need to create markers on the fly so I need to use geoxml3. My problem is that replacing the last line with this

```
var m = parser.createMarker(place);
```

causes this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined
```

Maybe because it cannot load the icon `http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png` because of its origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) is a google maps API v3 kml parser.  If you translate the response from the places API into kml, you could make that work, but I don't know why you would do that.  Perhaps you could explain why you want to use geoxml3, you don't need it for the stated goal "to create markers on the fly", as you can do that easily with the google maps API v3 without it.